# Private Listening session on Roku TV

Tags: roku-tv, private-listening

I am trying to initiate Private Listening session on Roku TV. I am receiving JSON response:

`{"notify":"authenticate","param-challenge":"VLCp54BDvDkRHaFyyNky1g==","timestamp":"424034.121"}`

when connecting to the "/ecp-session" on TV IP address (port 8060). Can anyone tell how to generate a value for the "param-response" in my response?

`{"request":"authenticate","param-response":"???????","request-id":"0"}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found it on GitHub at this [url](https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/83819)
It's very simple:

1. Take the value of param-challenge (don't decode it)
2. Append the constant key "F3A278B8-1C6F-44A9-9D89-F1979CA4C6F1"
3. Hash it using SHA-1
4. Encode the hash to base64

```cs
    const string KEY = "F3A278B8-1C6F-44A9-9D89-F1979CA4C6F1";
    
    string paramChallengeWithKey = paramChallenge + KEY;
    byte[] hash = sha1(paramChallengeWithKey);
    
    string paramResponse = base64(hash);
```